# Fix a broken Power Supply using existing connector (Newbie)

Tags: power-supply, dc, repair

I am hoping to attempt to fix my childrens ride on electric car as the power supply was left charging and has cracked / broken (see pics).

[image: Original Broken Power Supply]
[image: Connector]

I am completely new to electronics, but was hoping to replace the power supply and get the car working again.

The power supply seems to have a non-standard connector and I cannot seem to source a replacement on the internet so the only option "I can see" is to replace the power supply and solder / re-attach the connector to it, hence this question.

I have measured the voltage across the car battery and getting about 13 volts so can I assume that this has not been damaged?

I have looked at a few articles / videos such as -

https://superuser.com/questions/166876/can-i-patch-my-laptop-power-cable

[Is it OK to solder a power cord?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81208/is-it-ok-to-solder-a-power-cord)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTAUupMxT1U

But the over-riding theme seems to be its fine to DONT MESS ABOUT unless you know what you are doing?

I am in the UK.

I was hoping that someone who knows what they are doing could describe if / how they would attempt to repair this (maybe there is an alternate way or the connector is not so non-standard).   They may also describe how dangerous is could be if done wrong?

I can at least then go forward knowing I can pay someone to complete the repair if I am not comfortable doing it myself.

EDIT: As this question has been put "on hold", here are some original notes that I did not post but probably should have to show where I had got to, but on reading the link again, think I would have to know how to design a power supply before asking how to repair one? yet individual questions regarding parts of the steps to repair on are OK on this site -

For the record, from those others links here is what I would do if I wasn’t concerned about safety.

- Cut the connector end off the broken adaptor, cut the end of the new replacement adaptor.
- From the picture, would separate the 2 wires.
- Strip wires tidily.
- Twine them (people seem to think this is better than just touching and solder).
- Solder them
- Heat shrink wrap each wire
- Heat shrink wrap the external wire around the join to keep tidy.
- Test the adaptor without letting it out of sight (but to be honest how would I know it was OK? I will check for heat in wire etc).

Comment: Really, if it looks like that, throw it away, this is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I only intend to use the connector bit on a newly purchased supply with equivalent specs? still a no go? thanks

Comment: That looks like an american 4-way trailer connector. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailer_Connector/North_America

Comment: @WickedW: Something has caused it to melt, and that is certainly not only depending on the quality of the power supply.

Comment: @PlasmaHH good point, I left it plugged in for a week or so and the case ended up cracking.

Comment: but it did not melt as such, that is some black tape around the outside that looks messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is note down the polarity of the connector, 
cut the wire off the old supply and wire it to a new 12v DC supply rated for the 1A output Making sure the polarity is correct to avoid burning out any reverse polarity protection diodes.

Comment: thanks @B-TECH, how would I note the polarity of the connector? do I take apart the existing supply and check how it connects internally?

Comment: @WickedW there is a drawing on the front of the power brick. The three metal prongs are redundantly connected to + and the hooded prong is connected to -.

Comment: Thanks to the people who took the time to reply, I went ahead with repair, I used the markings on each wire to note polarity for both adaptors wires, I also measured polarity using multimeter to be sure, I then soldered the 4 way connector onto the new adaptor and insulated, I did my best to check all was OK, and the kids are now driving around the back garden in the car.